# Maayan HaMitgaber in Alei Shur (Rabbi Wolbe)

Tags: mussar-ethics

Maayan HaMitgaber in Alei Shur (Rabbi Wolbe) -- very strong concept, but I cannot locate the first mention in R Wolbe's Volume 1.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some greater context? What was is said in relation to?